# Wit.ai API converse doesn't respond with bookmarked action

Tags: wit.ai, facebook-chatbot

I feel I must be doing something wrong in the API. I am following the weather example with a missing location. The story works fine.

However when I use the API over http using postman for testing purposes I cannot get it to raise the action after sending back the location from the user, It always returns a stop message. I think I must be not sending the correct context across or similar.

My understanding is as follows:

send across message 'I want to know the weather'
raises action from wit: 'Weather' (works correctly)
Respond with 'missingLocation'
wit replies with msg 'Which location do you want to know the weather for?' (works correctly)
I respond with 'Paris' in the message (no context all with same session)
wit replies with finding the entity 'Paris' but a 'stop' and no action. Here I would expect to get an action request again with everything I need to know this time. This is what happens when I use the story and test using the bot messenger.

Any ideas from anyone? I expect I need to respond with something more than just 'Paris' in the message

Thanks.

**Note:** the question was asked by "scruffjinks" on github before with no answer
https://github.com/wit-ai/wit/issues/301

Comment: Can you share your Wit.ai instance?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've build up my bot from scratch a few time to see if I've did something wrong in the story, but that didnt do anything. I've played around with the actions tab and got a better result but it's still unpredictable why I get a "Stop" or the Action I need.. I could really use some help with this